# How to get full mountpoint path name by the sturct fc_context

Tags: linux-kernel, namespaces, filesystems, kernel, kernel-module

In my kernel module, I've implemented a syscall hook named `fsconfig` to manage operations related to remounting readonly mountpoints. For instance, if a user executes `mount /dev/sda /tmp/mytest -o remount,ro`, I need to extract the string `/tmp/mytest` within the `fsconfig` hook.

To achieve this, I explored the kernel's approach of accessing an `fs_context` structure via a file descriptor. My goal is to retrieve the mount point path through this structure during the fsconfig syscall.

Initially, I attempted to utilize functions like `dentry_path_raw` starting from `fc_context->dentry`, but the resulting string was simply `"/"`, which didn't fulfill my requirements. I also explored using `d_path`, but it necessitated a `path` structure containing `dentry` and `vfsmount`, which `vfsmount` isn't accessible within the `fsconfig` syscall, rendering this approach impractical.

Finally, I came across the `__is_local_mountpoint` function in the kernel source code [(fs/namespace.c)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6/source/fs/namespace.c#L761). This function suggests iterating through all mountpoints by accessing the namespace of the current task via current. I adapted this code to compare the mnt_root of each mountpoint with the fs_context root, successfully identifying the corresponding mount, the code is here.

```
ns =  current->nsproxy->mnt_ns;
lock_ns_list(ns);
list_for_each_entry(mnt, &ns->list, mnt_list) {
    if (fc->root == mnt->mnt.mnt_root) {
        target_dentry = mnt->mnt.mnt_root;
        path.dentry = target_dentry;
        path.mnt = &mnt->mnt;
        break;
    }
}
unlock_ns_list(ns);
```

However, there's a significant concern regarding the usage of `namespace_sem` in namespace.c. The declaration of `namespace_sem` is static (`static DECLARE_RWSEM(namespace_sem);`), meaning it cannot be accessed directly within the module, posing potential risks.

**Now, my primary questions are:**

1. Is there a secure method to obtain the mount point path through `fs_context` without requiring modifications to kernel code? (Assuming `fs_context` always corresponds to a mounted file system.)
2. If we're limited to iterating through mountpoints, how can we address the challenge of not being able to access the semaphore securely?

(Its can be assumed the kernel version >= 6.6.)